# About finite presentations of finitely presented faithful modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ a finitely presented $R$-module. If
$R^m \rightarrow R^n \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ is a finite presentation of $M$ with $m<n$, then it is easy to see that $M$ is faithful.
I am interested in the converse. So let $M$ be a finitely presented faithful $R$-module with $\mu(M)$ being its minimal number of generators. Does there always exist a presentation of $M$, say $R^m \rightarrow R^{\mu(M)} \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, where $m<\mu(M)$? A stronger question is, if $K \rightarrow R^{\mu(M)} \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of $R$-modules, must $\mu(K)<\mu(M)$? And an weaker question is, does there at least exist some presentation $R^m \rightarrow R^n \rightarrow M \rightarrow 0$, with $m<n$?

Comment: OK, the `stronger question' has a negative answer. Take $R:= k[X,Y]/(XY)$ and $M:=R/Rx \oplus R/Ry$. Then $M$ is a faithful $R$-module and $\mu(M)=2$. Now the natural projection from $R^2$ to $M$ has kernel $K=\{(a,b)\in R^2 | a\in I \text{ and } b\in J\}$. But K is not a cyclic $R$-module.

Comment: You have essentially answered all parts of your question here. To avoid having to deal with the grading you could consider $k[\![x,y]\!]/(xy)$ and $M=R/(x) \oplus R/(y)$ and follow the same argument. This ring is local, so any presentation is built from a minimal one by adding copies of $R$ to both free modules in equal measure and potentially adding additional copies to $R^m$.

Comment: So if i understand it correctly, we take R:=k[[X,Y]]/(XY) amd M:=R/(x)\oplus R/(y). Then we have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow K \rightarrow R^2\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$, where $\mu(K)>1$. So if $0\rightarrow K' \rightarrow R^2\rightarrow M\rightarrow 0$, then by Schanuel's lemma, $R^2\oplus K \cong R^2\oplus K'$, implying that $\mu(K')>1$. So of $.... \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow F_0$ is a minimal free resolution of $M$, then $F_0$ and $F_1$ both have rank 2. Finally, since every free resolution of $M$ is obtained from a minimal free resolution by adjoining some copies of $R$, we are done.

Comment: Importantly, we cannot add copies to $F_0$ without adding at least as many copies to $F_1$, as specifically, a resolution of $M$ is produced from a minimal one by adding copies of the complex $0 \to R \xrightarrow{id} R \to 0$. As an aside, direct sums over a local ring are cancellative, so, in your notation, you have $K \cong K'$.  This $K$ is often written $\Omega^R_1(M)$ and would be termed \textbf{the} (first) syzygy of $M$.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation.